# Behaviour of unnecessary or redundant calls to std::unordered_map::reserve

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, unordered-map

### Intro

I'm looking for clarification about the behaviour of the `reserve` method of `std::unordered_map`. Let's contrast with the case of `std::vector`. Quoting [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) on `std::vector::reserve`,

> Increase the capacity of the vector to a value that's greater or equal to `new_cap`. If `new_cap` is greater than the current `capacity()`, new storage is allocated, otherwise the method does nothing.

However, the corresponding page for [unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/reserve) just says

> Sets the number of buckets to the number needed to accomodate at least count elements without exceeding maximum load factor and rehashes the container, i.e. puts the elements into appropriate buckets considering that total number of buckets has changed. Effectively calls `rehash(std::ceil(count / max_load_factor()))`.

### My Question

I want to know

1. Does the standard make any similar guarantees about `std::unordered_map::reserve`; and, if not
2. Is there a check that can be done to ensure that an unnecessary, possibly costly rehash is not performed? For example, if my map currently has size `count`, and I'm going to increase its size to `new_count`, should I only call  reserve if

   ```
   std::ceil(new_count / max_load_factor()) > std::ceil(count / max_load_factor())
   ```

   ?

Comment: No, there doesn't appear to be any requirement that `rehash()` do nothing if its postconditions are already met before the call. The caller can, of course, check those postconditions itself, and skip calling `rehash()` (or `reserve()`, which is equivalent to `rehash()`) if not warranted.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf page 773 is the req's for reserve and rehash

Comment: I would rather think if you need to reserve at all. Most of the times, default policies are OK.

Comment: What's the confusion? The text you cited tells you what it means. What "similar guarantees" are you talking about and why do you expect them?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I guess "similar guarantees" was vague wording, but @AndyG's answer put it pretty well, basically just was wondering if a rehash will still be performed if the postconditions of the rehash are already met. As for why I was expecting them, that was purely on the basis of `std::vector`'s behaviour.

Comment: @SergeyA That was my first thought, but stress testing in the overarching application has revealed a bottleneck around this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the standard make any similar guarantees [`reserve` should do nothing if the postconditions of `rehash` (which it calls) are satisfied: both `bucket_count() >= size() / max_load_factor()` and `bucket_count() >= n` where `n` is the argument to `reserve`)] about `std::unordered_map::reserve`?

No it does not.

> Is there a check that can be done to ensure that an unnecessary, possibly costly rehash is not performed?

You could check the postconditions I edited into your question above in [...] but there is no built in function to do it for you.

Relevant standard: §23.2.5/Table 103 [unord.req] (n3337)